# scala-maven-plugin : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to run a simple Scala Hello World program using scala-maven-plugin from the command line in my Ubuntu VM running in Win-7 host OS.

I tried to execute in the following two ways :-

1. `mvn scala:run -DmainClass=com.infoobjects.HelloWorld`
2. Declaring the main class in a launcher tag in pom.xml and then executing `mvn scala:run` from the command line

But I am getting ClassNotFoundException in either case.

Directory Structure :-

Project > src > main > scala > com > infoobjects > HelloWorld.scala

Thanks in advance.

Here's my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>sparkplay</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
        <launchers>
        <launcher>
        <id>launcher1</id>
        <mainClass>com.infoobjects.HelloWorld</mainClass>
        </launcher>
        </launchers>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the exception being thrown? Which `class` is not found? And it would be nice if you can provide snippets from your `pom.xml` (especially concerning the main class)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infoobjects.HelloWorld
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:154)

Comment: Can you check the `target` folder? Is there any class compiled under `classes` there? Have you tried `mvn compile` first and then `mvn scala:run ...`?

Comment: One common pitfall is forgetting to put the package on top of your main class. By checking the `target` folder you can confirm whether the compiles `.class` file resides in the proper directory corresponding to the package hierarchy. If this is the case please update the question with a snippet of your `HelloWorld` file.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem.

It says no Source file to compile when I try to run, though I have forced Eclipse to use the folder as a Source folder using the context menu

Comment: Have you checked the `target` folder? Have you checked `package` at top of your main file? Can you try without eclipse? Just use `mvn` in command line first.

Comment: I have used the package at top of the main file

`package com.infoobjects`

There is no `target` folder because the scala compiler is unable to find any sources to compile.

yes, I have tried without eclipse `mvn compile` says 'Build Successful' because the problem is that the `scala-maven-plugin` is unable to find the Scala source file 'HelloWorld.scala'

Comment: Are you sure the file hierarchy is correct? Verify that `src`, `main`, and `scala` folders are correctly spelled (no uppercase character). The last option would be trying to find a working sample and base your work on that sample.

Comment: Yes the names are correctly spelled.

I ran `mvn scala:compile` and finally I got my scala classes to compile and `target` folder contains the class files now.

I am now looking into why `mvn scala:run` was giving me error. I will update here soon.

Once again, thanks a lot Nader :)

Comment: No problem. One more thing, sorry for being a bit repetitive, are you sure that in `target` folder you have a folder structure like this: `classes/com/infoobjects/HelloWorld.class`?

Comment: Can you share the output log of : `mvn compile`, `mvn scala:run -DmainClass=com.infoobjects.HelloWorld` and `ls target/classes/com/infoobjects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pom.xml has schema's issue : `<executions>` should not be child of `<configuration>`. So everything under `<executions>` is ignored

see [Maven Model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-model/maven.html#class_plugin)